# A Good Barebones TV Remote App

Tags: android

I am looking for a simple bare-bones TV remote app for an android phone. I would like it to just be able to do the basics, and work with as many TVs as possible. I want it to be like those universal remotes for sale on line that advertise themselves as working with all TVs. It would be preferable if it was open source.

## Notes

- My phone does have an IR sensor

Comment: The important requirement here is that your phone does indeed possess an infrared blaster.

Comment: Not 100% sure which would match (I'm having different requirements ;) – but be welcome to check my list of apps for [TV devices & Co.](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_mmdevices#group_679). Should at least narrow down your search while waiting for the perfect answer :)

Comment: An IR sensor is markedly different from an IR blaster (which you're probably referring to)